# How to combine and sum duplicates in r dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Given a dataframe popcorn in R such as the following

| Year | Order Number | Product SKU | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | 4920299 | Medium | 4.5 |
| 2016 | 4920307 | Small | 3.5 |
| 2016 | 4920307 | Small | 3.5 |
| 2016 | 4920485 | Large | 5 |

How can I convert to wide format and sum the values for any repeated/duplicate order numbers:

| Year | Order Number | Small | Medium | Large |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016 | 4920299 | 0 | 4.5 | 0 |
| 2016 | 4920307 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| 2016 | 4920485 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

I know to use `spread()` to convert rows to column, but there are duplicate order numbers, so I can not do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pivot_wider` from tidyr package, use `sum` to summarise duplicates and set to 0 cells with no values.

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df, names_from = ProductSKU, values_from = Price, values_fn = sum, values_fill = 0)[, c(1,2,4,3,5)]
# A tibble: 3 × 5
   Year OrderNumber Small Medium Large
  <int>       <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1  2016     4920299     0    4.5     0
2  2016     4920307     7    0       0
3  2016     4920485     0    0       5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 df %>% group_by_at(vars(Year,OrderNumber,ProductSKU)) %>% summarise(. , Price=sum(Price,na.rm = T)) %>% ungroup() %>%
     pivot_wider(. , names_from = c('ProductSKU'),values_from = Price,values_fill = 0)
```

Here is the step-by-step explanation what the code means:
Using the tidyverse family of packages the df is piped %>% into the first function, group_by_at.

group_by_at groups the data frame by the variables "Year", "OrderNumber", and "ProductSKU".

Then, the summarise function computes the sum of the "Price" variable. In case of missing values, you can add (na.rm = T) to remove missing values.

Then the ungroup function removes the grouping established before.

Finally, (pivot_wider)  is used to reshape the data frame from long to wide format, by pivoting the values from the "Price" column and creating a new column for each unique value in the "ProductSKU" column, replacing missing values with 0 (values_fill = 0).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
reshape2::dcast(df1, Year+Order_Number~Product_SKU, sum)

  Year Order_Number Large Medium Small
1 2016      4920299     0    4.5     0
2 2016      4920307     0    0.0     7
3 2016      4920485     5    0.0     0
```